# How can send the credentials to call the service?

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

Ho to make basic authentication or send the credential information to service?

I have added a service reference (JAVA service reference) to the solution. When i tried to make a call to service, it hits an error saying unauthorised service request. How can I send the credentials when I call a service?As soon as i enter the user name and password in the login window, it should send the credentials to call the service.
I am new to WCF I have earlier used asmx procedure. Ho can i do this?

```
public partial class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ServiceReference2.ESIVisServicePortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference2.ESIVisServicePortTypeClient();

        ServiceReference2.PartType part = new ServiceReference2.PartType();
        part.partnumber = "A2040000049";
        ServiceReference2.ResponseType response = client.getPart2D(part);
        Console.WriteLine("Major: " + response.major + " Minor: " + response.minor);
    }
}

   <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="VisualizationSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <!--<security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>-->
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm=""/>
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="VisualizationSoapBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <!--<security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="Windows"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>-->
              <security mode="None">
                <transport  proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://vissvc-test.e.corpintra.net:80/VisSvcNative/DAIESIVisService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VisualizationSoapBinding1"
            contract="ServiceReference2.ESIVisServicePortType" name="ESIVisServicePort1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In asmx i used, `  private void InitExt()
        {

```
        if (this.Url == null || this.Url == "")
        {
            this.Url = ServiceConfiguration.URL;
        }
        this.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        //3.5 change - Lambda expressions
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    }

    public bool Authentify(string username, string password)
    {
        if (m_boolEnableProxy.ToLower() == "true")
        {
            WebProxy px = new WebProxy("proxy", 80);
            px.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = px;
        }

        m_strUsername = username;
        NetworkCredential _nwcAuthentify = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        this.Credentials = _nwcAuthentify.GetCredential(new Uri(this.Url), "basic");
        return this.Credentials != null;            
    }


    public void SetEndpoint(string url)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            this.Url = url;
        }
    }

    `
```

and get the session cookie

```
 protected string GetSessionCookie()
    {
        string ret = "";
        WebResponse res;
        if (m_webRequest != null)
        {
            res = base.GetWebResponse(m_webRequest);
            if (res != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < res.Headers.Keys.Count; i++)
                {
                    string key = res.Headers.Keys.Get(i);
                    string smsession = res.Headers.Get(i);
                    if (key == ServiceConfiguration.HEADER_COOKIE_NAME_C || key == ServiceConfiguration.HEADER_COOKIE_NAME_SETC || smsession.IndexOf(ServiceConfiguration.COOKIE_SMSESSION) > -1)
                    {
                        int index = smsession.IndexOf(ServiceConfiguration.COOKIE_SMSESSION) + ServiceConfiguration.COOKIE_SMSESSION.Length;
                        // Trim front
                        smsession = smsession.Substring(index);
                        index = smsession.IndexOf(ServiceConfiguration.HEADER_COOKIE_SEPARATOR);
                        // Trim end
                        ret = smsession.Substring(0, index);
                        // End loop
                        //break;
                        i = res.Headers.Keys.Count;
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }            
        return ret;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        //apptoken name to be sent instead of caller app name - 10.1
        this.RequestSoapContext.Addressing.From = new Uri(appToken, UriKind.Relative);     

        WebRequest req = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        req.Headers.Add(ServiceConfiguration.HEADER_COOKIE_NAME_C, ServiceConfiguration.HEADER_COOKIE_VALUE);
        req.Method = ServiceConfiguration.REQUEST_METHOD;
        req.ContentType = ServiceConfiguration.REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE;            
        string smsession = GetSMSessionCookie();
        if (smsession != "")
        {
            req.Headers.Add(ServiceConfiguration.HEADER_COOKIE_NAME_C, smsession);
        }

        m_webRequest = req;

        return req;

    }

I am using .net 4.0 C# 2010 winforms.
```

Comment: According to your bindings the service has no security: `security mode="None"` Can you find out from the creator of the SOAP Service what type of security the service is actually using?

Comment: @ Jonas - 
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="Service1Soap" >
<security mode="None"> <transport proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
this is the mode which they expecting to use.

Comment: So there seems to be no security built into the service. Again, ping them to see how you are supposed to send the credentials. Maybe you need to specify a token, which you get by calling another method or something, or maybe you need to pass them as parameters on every call.

Comment: Is this a SOAP Service or simple Web Service?

Comment: @JonasStawski - Yes, its SOAP service. Seems we need to do a basic authentication first and store username and password in a cookie (using windows desktop application) we authenticate the username and password of our company's customized portal and store in a cookie and then get the session cookie from the Siteminder and then pass it to service. We only pass the session(it is a big token generated). The username and password is stored throughout the request. But the session token changes for every request we send.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx), most likely you are looking to do something like this:

> client.ClientCredentials.Username.Username = username;
>   client.ClientCredentials.Username.Password = password;

Comment: Try changing the security mode on the config to Message and see if that works, but that would only work if the service is setup the same way. You truly need to get some docs or talk to the creator of the service.